# Wavefunction Renormalization in Wess-Zumino Model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, supersymmetry, effective-field-theory

In [Modern Supersymmetry: Dynamics and Duality](https://books.google.com/books?id=1JMf-fcnOHYC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), on page 134 and 135 in section 8.2, the authors studied the wavefunction renormalization of the [Wess-Zumino model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wess%E2%80%93Zumino_model).

The kinetic terms are given by

$$\mathcal{L}_{kin}=Z(m,m^{\dagger},\lambda,\lambda^{\dagger},\mu,\Lambda)\partial_{\mu}\phi^{\ast}\partial^{\mu}\phi+iZ(m,m^{\dagger},\lambda,\lambda^{\dagger},\mu,\Lambda)\bar{\psi}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi,$$

where $m$ and $\lambda$ are spurion fields (i.e. coupling coustants treated as background chiral superfield) in the tree level superpotential

$$W_{eff}=\frac{m}{2}\Phi^{2}+\frac{\lambda}{3}\Phi^{3}\equiv W_{tree},$$

where $\Phi(x,\theta,\bar{\theta})$ is the [chiral superfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermultiplet), and $\Lambda$ is the UV-cutoff.

Next, the authors claimed two things:

1. If we integrate out modes $\mu>m$, we obtain the wavefunction renormalization factor

$$Z=1+c|\lambda|^{2}\ln\left(\frac{\Lambda^{2}}{\mu^{2}}\right).$$

2. If we integrate out modes $\mu$ below $m$, we obtain the wavefunction renormalization factor

$$Z=1+c|\lambda|^{2}\ln\left(\frac{\Lambda^{2}}{|m|^{2}}\right).$$

In the above expressions, $c$ is a constant determined by the perturbative calculations.

***Can anybody give me the perturbative calculation (at one-loop) in detail? I don't know how to get the above expressions for $Z$.***